# What was the liquid in the trash compactor?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope, death-star

When Chewbacca, Luke, Han, and Leia escape the detention block aboard the Death Star, they find themselves in a trash compactor filled with enough murky liquid to hide a dianoga.

### What is the liquid?  Is it sewage?

Comment: Could be sewage, or could be food waste. If you leave a bin bag for too long with rotting food, it starts to form. A murky pool.

Comment: The answer is simple: You don't want to know.

Comment: There were a lot of stormtroopers on that Death Star, eating a lot of food.  Applying Conservation of Mass...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Sewage, food waste and some industrial byproducts

> Luke threw him an exasperated look but jumped into the darkness of the
> opening. Han fired off a few more quick shots to create a cover of
> smoke, then dove headfirst down the chute—
>
> **Right into some of the foulest muck and garbage the galaxy had ever
> seen. Clumps of half-rotted garbage swirled with the waste that was
> being pumped in from the bathrooms. Sticky flecks of blackened fruit
> and unidentifiable food clung to battered crates and scrap metal. Han
> gagged as he came up for air, grateful he’d kept his mouth closed as
> he came down.** There was a single light overhead, illuminating just how
> little there was to see. Chewie had found a small platform leading to
> a hatch but was clearly struggling to get it open. The sound of Luke
> sloshing around, up to his waist in crud, bounced off the impossibly
> high walls.
>
> <sub><sup>[Star Wars: A New Hope: The Princess, the Scoundrel, and the Farm Boy](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/A_New_Hope:_The_Princess,_the_Scoundrel,_and_the_Farm_Boy)</sup></sub>