# Why would there be water in the Death Star's trash compactor?

Tags: star-wars, a-new-hope

Water can't be compressed. Even with 150 times the normal atmospheric pressure (such as at the bottom of oceans), it gets compressed by less than 1%.

This would affect the mechanism of trash compactor, for sure. Totally submerged trash wouldn't get compacted at all.

Why was there water in the trash compactor of the Death Star? And, why did they turn on the compactor without filtering out water from the trash (they could certainly drain water using a small hose)?

Comment: It's not water but actually sewage and industrial by-products, as mentioned by Valorum in her here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116083/what-was-the-liquid-in-the-trash-compactor?rq=1

Comment: @Shreedhar So how is it not water?

Comment: @Raditz_35 because there was poop in it too :p

Comment: I don't know, I'm sure it's explained in some comic book about Star Wars trash management, however it's a franchise about space magic and people fighting with swords even though pistols and planet destroying weapons are available. I'm sure they'll just "force compress" it

Comment: @Raditz_35 *laser swords ;)

Comment: @Shreedhar `as mentioned by Valorum in her here` what does this mean?

Comment: @Shreedhar It didn't answer the question..

Comment: @WhiteWidow `half-rotted garbage swirled with the waste that was being pumped in from the bathrooms.` that sounds like it answers your question

Comment: It was just a suggested edit to that liquid in the the trash compactor isn't water.

Comment: the dupe does indeed neither question nor answer why liquids would end up in a trash compactor, instead of in some sweage recycling system.
Or how, BTW, a large organism could survive in a regularly compacted space.

Comment: @ths I believe how the creature survives has been asked and answered before. As for why the liquids there `Sewage, food waste and some industrial byproducts`: When you put food waste in a bin is it completely solid or does it have some liquid in it too? Work from there.

Comment: Why are we talking about sewage as though it doesn't have water in it? How does calling it "sewage" answer this question? I feel like we just went "eww, poop, ok conversation's over."

Comment: the point is that it doesn't make any sense to put anything wet in there. any watery waste should be dried first, or the compactor should have a drain to recover liquids.

Comment: Just as they could drain the water using a hose, they could also "drain" the water by having pipes or vents around the periphery of the compactor, such that the water would be forced out through said pipes *as the mechanism compacted.*  You could even argue that there appears to be evidence of such drainage in the fact that the water level **doesn't appear to be rising while they were trying to escape the closing walls.**

Comment: @Steve-O that can be an answer..

Comment: Done and done :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What was the liquid in the trash compactor?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116083/what-was-the-liquid-in-the-trash-compactor)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is addressed in the [Official Star Wars Fact File #57](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Official_Star_Wars_Fact_File_57). The waste includes **sewage, food waste and organics** which are then left to fester. All of these would obviously contain amounts of water.

> *All waste, from durasteel girders to **organic rubbish**, found its way to
>   one of the many trash compactors in the Death Star. As such, the
>   Rebels found themselves swimming in a stinking pool that was filled
>   with scrap.*

As to why there's still water in the chamber that our heroes land in, this is addressed in the [Death Star Technical Companion](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_Technical_Companion). While *some* effort has already been made to reclaim and recycle free water, by this point in the 'compaction and disposal' process the bins are **magnetically sealed** to prevent cross-contamination with other bins.

> *The rest was sent through long waste chutes to one of the numerous
>   trash compactors for each zone. During the rescue of Princess Leia
>   from the Death Star's detention block, the princess blasted into just
>   such a waste chute. The trash would then be compacted into the
>   smallest possible size and then moved to a jettison compartment along
>   one of the trenches. **Each of the bins and compactors was magnetically
>   sealed so that waste materials wouldn't leak into nearby compartments.***

We also see in the [Death Star Owner's Technical Manual](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Death_Star_Owner%27s_Technical_Manual) that the dianoga are not merely tolerated but are actually bred and housed by the station's waste disposal personnel. It's not clear whether this is an *officially sanctioned* decision or just staff doing things to make their lives easier but either way, maintaining a wet, swampy condition in the waste bins is presumably an essential part of keeping these useful scavengers safe and happy.

> *Sometimes called 'garbage squid', dianoga evolved as marine scavengers
>   on the swamp world Vordan. Ages ago, dianoga slithered into the hold
>   of a space freighter, and the creatures quickly spread their
>   populations to many planets. **Thriving in sewers and river canals of
>   large urban areas throughout the galaxy, dianoga feed on all types of
>   refuse, and can consume almost anything except pure metals**. A dianoga
>   possesses seven tentacles it used for locomotion and to catch food,
>   and has a single, flexible eyestalk, which can extend around corners,
>   or up like a periscope from underwater.*
>
> ***Because dianogas can consume vast quantities of garbage, the Death
>   Star's service sector not only tolerates their presence, but actually
>   breeds them for use in the trash compactors.***

Comment: Oh would you look at that the dupe close was correct.

Answer (score 3):

Just as they could drain the water using a hose, they could also "drain" the water by having pipes or vents around the periphery of the compactor, such that the water would be forced out through said pipes as the mechanism compacted.

You could even argue that there appears to be evidence of such drainage in the fact that *the water level doesn't appear to be rising* while they were trying to escape the closing walls.